# Limit parallel builds to a specific number in Jenkins

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins, parallel-processing

I have a number of builds in my Jenkinsfile which now run in parallel. But the master server is a bit overstrained. So my idea is to limit it's builds to a configured value *concurrentBuilds*.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44085 inspired me but I'm a bit stuck in my plan. I have a list of services which now gathered in a map which are run in parallel like this:

```
def stepsForParallel = [:]
stage('read modules') {
  readMavenPom().modules.findAll { module ->
    module.endsWith('-service')
  }.each { service ->
   stepsForParallel[service] = transformIntoStep(service) // this returns { build module } to avoid immediate execution
  }
}
stage('modules') {
  parallel stepsForParallel
}
```

The build function does use parallel too. So it I get a lot of parallel tasks.

My idea was to create a [LinkedBlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) (let's call it *stepDeque*) that gathers all steps that should be done in parallel. Then I'd create a second one (let's call it *workingDeque*) with a size of the configured  *concurrentBuilds*.

But then my issue arises: as far as I know I can only run parallel on a map. So, when one of the tasks of the workingDeque finishes I have a free thread.

So my question is: when I poll a job from stepDeque and add it to workingDeque, is there a way to solely run the step I just added? Or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a `Step` class which knows its dependents. At the start I gather all steps and put them in a LinkedBlockQueue and I create *n* workers using

```
def worker = [:]
maxConcurrentSteps.times {
  worker["worker${it}"] = {
    Step work = getWork() // uses take() to get new work
    while (work != null) {
      work.run()
      work = getWork()
    }
  }
}
```